# In dm-verity, why does the entire hash tree need to be verified?

Tags: linux, security, android

Based on this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/717470/284826), apparently dm-verity attempts to verify a block when a block is attempted to be accessed. When verifying a block, it goes up the hash tree to verify the root hash.

Why not just end with verifying the hash of the block being accessed?

Based on the answer, it seems to suggest that the dm-verity hash tree (merkle tree) actually contains the hash of every block in each respective leaf. If you have the hashes of all blocks in the leaves, why is there a need to verify the entire block device for every block access instead of only verifying the block being accessed?

Answer (score 0):

So, let's start with what this is supposed to do: cryptographically verify that a block device (image) is the one that you're expecting it to be.

To do that, you need to cryptographically sign every bit on the disk; if a bit changes, there needs to be a way of detecting that.

So, just splitting up my block device into blocks of the same length, and computing a checksum on each of them, is not enough. If I want to modify the file system image, then I will obviously also alter the checksum so that it fits after the fact!

Instead, you need to sign the checksum (that's better than signing the whole block, because, well, assuming that operation is even defined, it would take ages using the cryptographical math we know today to verify).

You can hence either sign every checksum individually, or you calculate a checksum over all checksums, and then just sign that.

So, you go for the latter.

But if you only verify just the single block, and not that the hash of the block together with the other hashes actually combine to give the one root hash that's actually been signed, then you're back at the state where if I modify the block device image in a block, I'll obviously also fix the block's hash. It's not signed, so nobody would detect that.

Comment: Thank you. I have a follow up question. Are these the steps for verification? 1. When mounting, the signature of the root hash is decrypted to get the signed root hash, and this signed root hash is stored in RAM 2. Whenever a block in the device is to be read, you use the data from the block and build the root hash using the hash tree. 3. You compare the computed root hash with the signed root hash. The reason why I'm guessing #1 happens is because I would think it is way too slow to decrypt the signature at every block read

Comment: 1. There's nothing encrypted. The hash lies there, in plaintext; it's signed, but that doesn't mean encrypted. *checking the signature* might actually look a lot like **en**crypting the the hash, mathematically! 2. yes. 3. yes.

Comment: Most digital signing is done via asymmetic encryption, so is it not safe to say that "verifying the digitial signature" is the same as "decrypting and compare the decrypted value to the value you are given"?

Comment: Also, my comment (or my intended thought) may be slightly incorrect. It seems like "veritysetup open" actually might be re-calculating the entire hashtree (and the roothash) of the device to compare with the signed root hash. I was actually thinking it wouldn't re-calculate the hashtree. I thought only when a block is being read, it would use the provided hashtree along with the block read to recompute the roothash to compare with the signed roothash